# Read Device Token for iPhone Push Notification

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications, devicetoken

I try to implement push notification in my iPhone application. I have create Provisioning Profile and App-id for push notification and add this certificates into Xcode. Connect iPhone device to mac system and build application through device for read Device token using the following code.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    NSLog(@"didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:\n%@", deviceToken);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

But it returns error.. like

> *didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application 2012-07-18
>   14:18:08.597 Z2NotifyMe[1874:707]
>   didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment'
>   entitlement string found for application" UserInfo=0x11fee0
>   {NSLocalizedDescription=no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string
>   found for application}*

I have remove all old certificates in Xcode and my device, then re-create all certificate newly then execute above same code it returns same above error.

Please help solve this problem.

Thanks..

Comment: Did u try to create a new provisioning profile from scratch? did u configure your appId to enable push notification in the Provisioning Portal?

Comment: Yes, I enable push notification on my Provisioning Portal.

Answer (score 0):

Register your device using the following code :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
```

In the `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method.

I hope that the device on which you are trying is not Jailbroken.

Comment: Yes, I already put this code in  applicationDidFinishLaunching but its return same error.

Comment: I am not trying Jailbroken methods.

Comment: Have u created the SSL certificate?

Comment: didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application

Comment: The SSL certificate is not created properly... Please regenerate the certificate and try again..

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when your code signing identity does not have push notification enabled.
Check out this link:

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services

http://blog.martinreichart.com/2010/01/getting-iphone-push-notifications-to-work/

Comment: I am already try above link but i get error like---    no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application

Comment: didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application

Comment: Can you open your provisioning profile in textEdit & find <key>aps-environment</key>.If your profile does not contain this then your profile is not correctly set up for push notification.Try to recreate your provisioning profile in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I did all the steps correctly but i still got this error.

Try doing the following steps, it helped me:
1) Go to you Provisioning Profile -> Provisioning
2) Press the "edit" button in the right hand side near your app provisioning profile - > then modify
3) Make some change here, it doesn't really matter what the change is, this is just to trigger a new profile. Unselect one of the devices, or change the name, you can change it back later.
4) press the "submit" button
5) download the profile and drag it to Xcode. (delete your old profile in Xcode before)

Comment: I try above steps and i get same error like ....   didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application

Comment: If you have any idea to solve this error  --  didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application

Comment: Not really, there can be a lot of small issues that I can't know about, like with the project settings in xcode. So my suggestion to u is, create a new project in Xcode and do all the push configuration from the beginning. I think it would take u less time to to this then finding the solution to your problem.